# Real time notification form Background Worker in ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: angular, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

I am very new in **ASP.NET Boilerplate** template. I have created a project where frontend is in Angular and Backend is in .NET Core. In my backend I have created a **Background Worker** using **PeriodicBackgroundWorkerBase** class. Now I need to send notification to the client. And in my Angular client when I receive the notification I need to show this in a alert message.

But I am not sure, how to implement this. Should I need to create a service class extending **IRealTimeNotifier** class? Or I need to create a Custom Hub extending **Hub** and **ITransientDependency** class?

One more thing, what about the subscription with **INotificationSubscriptionManager**?

Please give me some explanation with a good example both for **.net core and Angular.**